# How to reload all the app module using ui router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm not sure if I'm using the right methodology, please advice:
I have an AngularJS app, when a user login then I redirect from login page to the required page.

The issue:
Login button and profile pic are not update, because the 2 elements are inside module .run and index.html because both are inside the toolbar
[image]

How I can reload the main app (I'm not sure it's a good approach), if you have any other idea it will be great.

inside .run I'm trying to get the updated profile after login, it holds the status and the pic:

```
auth.authenticate(localStorageService.get('profile'), token)
```

in index.html I have the elements:

```
  <img ng-src="{{profile.picture}}" style="
                    width: 48px;
                    margin: 2px;
                    border-radius: 48px;
                    border: 0px solid #ddd;">
```

just by manually reload the page the above code will be executed and all will be updated as expected.

Comment: can use a directive that injects your auth service and displays correct element based on auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. Create a UserService and keep all user info in this module.
2. Use getter functions to get data from the service.
3. Inject UserService module to both places
   (where you keep your view info, in this case your '.run()' block(?)
   and where you change user status and data in Login service or Login
   controller).
4. Once the user is authenticated, update UserService module and that's it.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s9nma12m/9/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.service('UserService', [function () {
    var UserService = this;
    var _isAuthenticated = false;
    UserService.isAuthenticated = function () {
        return _isAuthenticated;
    };

    var _user = {
        name: 'Guest2'
    };
    UserService.getUserInfo = function () {
        return _user;
    };

    UserService.login = function () {
        // some logic...
        // update user data here:
        _user = {
            name: 'Peter Griffin'
        };
        _isAuthenticated = true;
    };
}]);

myApp.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', 'UserService',
    function ($scope, UserService) {
        $scope.isAuth = UserService.isAuthenticated;
    }]);

myApp.controller('headerCtrl', ['$scope', 'UserService',
    function ($scope, UserService) {
        $scope.isAuth = UserService.isAuthenticated;
        $scope.user = UserService.getUserInfo;
        $scope.login = UserService.login;
    }]);
```

Comment: This code is well written, works for me, thanks for the detailed example